# Getting rid of undefined in select options

Tags: javascript, html

I have code which reads  an uploaded text file and sorts it as options for different `<select>`.  Since i am using for loop and setting it less than file.length. All the options from text file are read correctly but once the text is done, the rest of the options show up as `undefined`. I wanted to know how to get rid of these `undefined`? If confusing, please comment below for further explanation.

Comment: Why do three loops? do one and increment i inside.

Comment: Your option isn't correct, instead of val you should use value.  And the value should be unique for each option:   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: @SPlatten Value does not need to be unique...

Comment: So are you looping over the results or the file? That is your issue.

Comment: @epascarello, it does it you want to identify which option was chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2uyj3rv/). It Worked for me for .txt file with content `Arif, John, Sonya, SuperGirl, The Flash, Batman, Suparman`

i added if statement to for loop, and combined your  3 loops into one

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i=i+3) {
      $('#name').append('<option val="1">' + results[i] + '</option>');
      $('#name2').append('<option val="1">' + results[i] + '</option>');
      if(typeof results[i+1] !== 'undefined') {
         $('#address').append('<option val="1">' + results[i+1] + '</option>');
         $('#address2').append('<option val="1">' + results[i+1] + '</option>');
      }
      if(typeof results[i+2] !== 'undefined') {
         $('#size').append('<option val="1">' + results[i+2] + '</option>');
         $('#size2').append('<option val="1">' + results[i+2] + '</option>');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i=i+3) {
```

or you should get value from file

```
$('#name').append('<option value="1">' + file[i] + '</option>');
```